# Execute the scripts at the same time if-else problem

Tags: php, concurrency, if-statement, file-locking

I can't use `flock` at the moment(server restrictions) so I am creating a alternative file lock system. Here is my code.

```
$dir = "C:\\wamp\\www\\test\\";
$files = scandir($dir);

for($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++) 
{   
    if(substr(strrchr($files[$i],'.csv'),-4) == '.csv')
    {           
        echo "File ".$files[$i]." is a csv"."</br>";
        if (file_exists("$dir$files[$i].lock"))
        {
            echo $files[$i]." has lock in place"."</br>";
            $i++;
        }
        else
        {
            if($file_handle = fopen("$dir$files[$i]", "rb"))
            {
                $file_lock_handle = fopen("$dir$files[$i].lock", "w");
                echo "Setting Lock"."</br>";

                //Do Logic

                fclose($file_handle);
                fclose($file_lock_handle);          

                sleep(3);
                unlink("$dir$files[$i].lock");
            }       
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //Do nothing
    }   
}
```

If I run these scripts side by side. It waits for the first script to be finished before it executes the second one. How can I run them concurrently? i.e. If a lock exists I want it to skip that file and go the the next one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a good example of this here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php#92731

Comment: Thanks a lot, exactly what I was trying to do!